# React get offset of element outside the component

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get the offsetTop, offsetLeft, offsetHeight, etc of an element that is outside my React component and pass the values as inline CSS to the React component.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  const top = document.getElementById("div1").offsetTop;
  const left = document.getElementById("div1").offsetLeft;
  const bottom = document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight;

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
         className="example"
         style={
           top: top,
           left: left,
           bottom: bottom,
         };
       ></div>
    );
  }
}
```

The code above gives `undefined` for `top`, `left`, and `bottom` offset values.

Comment: did you try to top: {this.top} ?

Comment: do you mean that the problem occurs at variable assigning stage? if so, the only reason I can think of is that there's no element with id "div1" as I was unable to reproduce this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Confirm the outside element already mount

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    state = { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0 }
    componentDidMount() {
        const top = document.getElementById( "div1" ).offsetTop;
        const left = document.getElementById( "div1" ).offsetLeft;
        const bottom = document.getElementById( "div1" ).offsetHeight;
        this.setState( { top, left, bottom } )
    }

    render() {
        const { top, left, bottom } = this.state;
        return (
            <div 
                className="example"
                style={
                   top: top,
                   left: left,
                   bottom: bottom,
                }
            ></div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are undefined because it looks like you want `top`, `left`, and `bottom` to be class properties.

Place them in your constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.top = document.getElementById("div1").offsetTop;
    this.left = document.getElementById("div1").offsetLeft;
    this.bottom = document.getElementById("div1").offsetHeight;
}
```

Access them with `{this.top}`, `{this.left}` etc.